# How to connect React Native app to Django REST API

Tags: python, django, react-native, django-rest-framework, integration

I'm in the process of connecting my React Native UI to Python Django backend using REST framework and unsure of how to go about fetching the data from backend.

I used the `fetch(`URL`)` as you can see in the SS below:

[image]

The error I get:

[image]

I also added my phone as an adb device and connected it through a USB cable before running the app, but same issue. Any suggestions as to how to go about React Native UI and Python Django REST API integration?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I hope it will help the next ones.
You cannot use a regular url when connecting DRF (or any other API framework) to a react native app so you need to tunnel it through a reverse proxy such as ngrok. Short answer is, download ngrok, put it in your environment variable then in your shell type :
`ngrok http 8000`
You will receive an https to replace your localhost:8000 in your API url. Good thing to do is to register to ngrok not to have to replace this new url too often, I think it is only stable for an hour or two if not registered.
Last but not least, in your CORS config whitelist (CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS), don't forget to put this new url or you'll get a 404.
Good luck